# Wordpress widget won't update when save is clicked

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

So this is my first attempt a creating a widget that has a functionality of creating a simple image rollover effect (if anyone wants it when it's done, leave me a message).

Now I downloaded a sample widget and made some changes, I still haven't touched the html part for the output so ignore that bit. Now my problem is, when I click save, the values in the fields go back to their default values, and they did not do this on the sample widget. Here's my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Image: Rollover Widget
 * Description: A widget that creates a rollover image effect with a hyperlink.
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: Zak Elas
 * Author URI:
 */


add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widget' );


function my_widget() {
    register_widget( 'MY_Widget' );
}

class MY_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    function MY_Widget() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'example', 'description' => __('A widget that creates a rollover image effect with a hyperlink. ', 'example') );

        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'Rollover Widget' );

        $this->WP_Widget( 'example-widget', __('Example Widget', 'example'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        //Our variables from the widget settings.
        $link = apply_filters('widget_link', $instance['link'] );
        $image = $instance['image'];
        $rollover_image = $instance['rollover_image'];

        echo $before_widget;

        // Display the widget link 
        if ( $link )
            echo $before_link . $link . $after_link;

        //Display the name 

            printf( '<p>' . __('Hey their Sailor! My name is %1$s.', 'example') . '</p>', $image );


            printf( '<p>' . __('Hey their Sailor! My name is %1$s.', 'example') . '</p>', $rollover_image );



        echo $after_widget;
    }

    //Update the widget 

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        //Strip tags from link and name to remove HTML 
        $instance['link'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['link'] );
        $instance['image'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['image'] );
        $instance['rollover_image'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['rollover_image'] );

        return $instance;
    }


    function form( $instance ) {

        //Set up some default widget settings.
        $defaults = array( 'link' => __('Example', 'example'), 'image' => __('/images/editorial.png', 'example') , 'rollover_image' => __('/images/editorial.png', 'example') );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>


        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>"><?php _e('link', 'example'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'link' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['link']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
        </p>


        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>"><?php _e('image', 'example'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['image']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'rollover_image' ); ?>"><?php _e('rollover_image:', 'example'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'rollover_image' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['rollover_image']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
        </p>



    <?php
    }
}

?>
```

And here is the sample widgets code

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: A simple Widget
 * Description: A widget that displays authors name.
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: Bilal Shaheen
 * Author URI: http://gearaffiti.com/about
 */


add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widget' );


function my_widget() {
    register_widget( 'MY_Widget' );
}

class MY_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    function MY_Widget() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'example', 'description' => __('A widget that displays the authors name ', 'example') );

        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'example-widget' );

        $this->WP_Widget( 'example-widget', __('Example Widget', 'example'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        //Our variables from the widget settings.
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $name = $instance['name'];
        $show_info = isset( $instance['show_info'] ) ? $instance['show_info'] : false;

        echo $before_widget;

        // Display the widget title 
        if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

        //Display the name 
        if ( $name )
            printf( '<p>' . __('Hey their Sailor! My name is %1$s.', 'example') . '</p>', $name );


        if ( $show_info )
            printf( $name );


        echo $after_widget;
    }

    //Update the widget 

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        //Strip tags from title and name to remove HTML 
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['name'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['name'] );
        $instance['show_info'] = $new_instance['show_info'];

        return $instance;
    }


    function form( $instance ) {

        //Set up some default widget settings.
        $defaults = array( 'title' => __('Example', 'example'), 'name' => __('Bilal Shaheen', 'example'), 'show_info' => true );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

        //Widget Title: Text Input.
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'example'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
        </p>

        //Text Input.
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>"><?php _e('Your Name:', 'example'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'name' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['name']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
        </p>


        //Checkbox.
        <p>
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance['show_info'], true ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_info' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_info' ); ?>" /> 
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_info' ); ?>"><?php _e('Display info publicly?', 'example'); ?></label>
        </p>

    <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id_base` should match the first argument for `WP_Widget`, and it should be lower case, no spaces:

```
$control_ops = array( 
    'width' => 300, 
    'height' => 350, 
    'id_base' => 'rollover_image_id' 
);

$this->WP_Widget( 
    'rollover_image_id', 
    __('Example Widget', 'example'), 
    $widget_ops, 
    $control_ops 
);
```

And you have a `get_field_name( 'image' )`
where it should be **`get_field_name( 'rollover_image' )`**.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$this->WP_Widget( 'example-widget', __('Example Widget', 'example'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
```

to this

```
$this->WP_Widget( 'my_widget', __('Example Widget', 'example'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
```

consructor id (which was **example-widget** and I have corected to **my_widget**) must be namespaced form (lowercase, nospace) of class name (which is **MY_Widget**).

This will work insaAllah.